# How to concatenate dynamic values with Jquery selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having Jquery function with an div id, I have to attached a dynamic value with that div id.
The div id name is **foodtypes**

```
$(function() {
var i = 0;
$('body').on('click','#foodtypes+i+ input',function() {
    console.log('foodtype function called')

});
```

But this method is never called.SO, i hardcoded the value of i as below then its working fine.

```
 $(function() {
var i = 0;
$('body').on('click','#foodtypes0 input',function() {
    console.log('foodtype function called')

});
```

Someone help me how to pass that or concatenate the variable dynamically.

Comment: You must be in a class, I saw this question yesterday. It's the same way you would concat a string to a variable. The selector is just a string.

Answer (score 1):

It's just string arithmetic in Javascript:

```
'#foodtypes' + i + ' input'
```

will produce this (if `i === 0`):

```
'#foodtypes0 input'
```

You can just add strings in Javascript and when you add a number to a string, the number is converted to a string before adding it onto the previous string.

Answer (score 1):

it should be:

```
$('body').on('click', '#foodtypes'+i+' input', function() {
    //do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use below code :

```
   $(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $('body').on('click','#foodtypes' + i + ' input',function() {
        console.log('foodtype' + i + ' function called');
    });
```